# Form is not filling table and returns blank page

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my HTML and PHP code that I'm trying to use to write the form into the table.
Once submit is being pressed its loading up the PHP but it is being returned as a blank screen.
Any help would be appreciated to help me move forward from this problem.

Here is the HTML code for the contact section of the page.

```
  </div>
        <!-- Contact Info -->
        <div class="row">

            </div> <!-- information end -->
            <!--Contact Form-->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <form class="col-md-12 contact-form" method="POST" action="beerewarded.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Name-->

                         <!--Email-->
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Email_Address" name="Email_Address" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="First_Name" name="First_Name" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>

                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>

                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Phone_Number" name="Phone_Number" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>

                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Birthday" name="Birthday" class="form-inp requie" type="date" placeholder="Birthday ">
                        </div>



                   <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="con_submit" class="site-button" type="submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- contact form end -->
```

Here is the PHP section of the file.

```
     <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "beeskneesbars_com";
 $password = "123456";
 $dbname = "beeskneesbars_com";

 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
$Email_Address = $_POST['Email_Address'];
 $First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
 $Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
 $Phone_Number = $_POST['Phone_Numebr'];
 $Birthday = $_POST['Birthday'];


 $insert_data = mysql_query('INSERT INTO Bee_Rewarded VALUES("$Email_Address", "$First_Name","$Last_Name","$Phone_Number","$Birthday",)');

 echo "Data are successfully save..."; }
         ?>
```

Comment: I don't see an input with name "insert" in your form. You can try <input id="con_submit" class="site-button" type="submit" name="insert" value="submit">

Comment: tried didn't make a difference :(

Comment: 1) use var_dump($_POST) to inspect your $_POST values and 2) also enable display_errors. 3) you are using mysql_query with mysqli extension

Comment: You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`.  Blank white screen usually indicates an error, but error reporting is turned off.  What do the logs say? Can you turn on error reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind, you have already added the name attribute for your submit button, please update your code in php file to execute an sql query to this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Bee_Rewarded VALUES('$Email_Address','$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Phone_Number','$Birthday') ";

    $insert_data = mysql_query($conn,$sql);

if($insert_data)
{
    echo 'Data Added Successfuly';
}
else
{
    echo 'Error In Adding Data';
}
```

Comment: made this edit and when its run it still returns a blank screen

Comment: I have tired this code and it has successfully posted to the table 

  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO Bee_Rewarded (Email_Address, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_Number, Birthday )
VALUES ( 'john@example.com', 'John', 'Doe', '07904596632', '08/09/1994')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


        $conn->close();

Comment: @ChristopherFewster Thank you for the update. I learnt mysql many many year back hence not well versed with the exact syntax. But what I did gather from your original query was that you forgot/missed the connection bit before executing the query. I am glad that you're now able to insert the values in the mysql table.